# T4MVC alternatives for ASP.NET 5?

Tags: asp.net-core, t4mvc, r4mvc

T4MVC is not supported yet or ever in ASP.NET 5. Is there any other similar solution ? I need strongly typed views and controllers names.

Comment: According to the latest comments here, T4 will be supported after all: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/272  

So far, I can't get T4MVC to work with ASP.NET 5 yet though, see my related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34399939/make-t4mvc-work-with-asp-net-5

Note also this project: https://github.com/totht91/TextTemplating

Answer (score 4):

Looks like there is a side project called [R4MVC](https://github.com/T4MVC/R4MVC) but it hasn't been updated in 5 months.

> R4MVC is a Roslyn code generator for ASP.NET MVC vnext apps that
>   creates strongly typed helpers that eliminate the use of literal
>   strings in many places

Answer (score 2):

As Stafford Williams pointed out, a side project was started a long time ago, but was stalled due to (at the time) breaking changes in the Roslyn compiler.

Luckily, the project was revived, and [R4MVC](https://github.com/T4MVC/R4MVC) has just released it's first alpha build, with more changes coming soon.

While the project works somewhat differently, and isn't using t4 templates, the end result is the same, and we're working to achieve feature parity with T4MVC in the near future.